# Extracting specific lines from multiple text files in the same folder for the entire folder

Tags: python-3.x

I am working with meteorological data that I wished to extract lines 319-356 for the grids that I am working with, for all the stations (the resultant text file should contain the header and the data in line 319-356). I have developed the following code in Python but it returned blank text files. May I know how should I improve it? Thank you in advance!

```
import os

for filename in os.listdir('P11'):
    if filename.endswith(".txt"):
        with open(os.path.join('P11', filename), 'r') as f:
            data = f.read()
            header = f.readline()
            content = f.readlines()[1:]
            needed_lines = content[320:357]
            output_strings = map(header, needed_lines)
            output_content = " ".join(output_strings)

        with open(os.path.join('P11', filename), 'wt') as outfile:
            outfile.write(output_content)
```

This is how the result should look like:
20080101
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.05
0.01
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.26
0.00
0.00
0.01
0.01
1.08
0.96
0.65
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.34
0.00

Answer (score 0):

This works. Replace your specific things as needed like the file names and the lines to get.

```
#file names
fileName = "./textFile"
outFileName = "./file2"
#open file
file = open(fileName)
#get each file line
lines = file.readlines()
#get rid of any new line characters
lines = [i.replace("\n", "") for i in lines]
print(lines)
#close file
file.close()
#open output
outF = open(outFileName, "w")
#make output
s = "".join(lines[2:6])
#write desired lines
outF.write(s)
#close output
outF.close()
```

Here it is without comments:

```
file = open(fileName)
lines = file.readlines()
lines = [i.replace("\n", "") for i in lines]
file.close()
outF = open("./file2", "w")
s = "".join(lines[2:6])
outF.write(s)
outF.close()
```

Edit: Some insight I have about your code is that using `with` essentially acts as a function so any variables created inside of it will not be visible outside of the `with`. This means that the second `with` will not see `output_content`. Also why are you using map()?

Comment: I was referring from others because I am new to Python haha

Comment: however, may I know what happen when it shows "PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '.idea'"?